# PyCharm Django Console good for performing manage.py tasks?

Tags: django, pycharm

There is a PyCharm Django Console.
Am I allowed to run manage.py things in that console, too?
What syntax I do enter to e.g. perform

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

in the django console?

Comment: The first google search I made for this turned up a result from the creators.  What happened when you searched for this issue? http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/running-tasks-of-manage-py-utility.html

Comment: Thank You. Manage.Py Utility is nice, yes. 
But I didn't ask for this tool, my aim was to find out, if I am able to run e.g. syncdb in the django console? (Menu: Tools -> Run Django Console...)

Comment: No, and why would you want to? Especially since Pycharm provides a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually run it the way you're thinking. To run the `manage.py` tasks in PyCharm, you do the following:

1. On the main menu, choose Tools | Run manage.py task, or press Alt R.
2. In the Enter manage.py task name dialog box, start typing the desired task name. As you type, the suggestion list shrinks to show the matching tasks only.

> Note that on typing an asterisk, PyCharm displays the complete list of available tasks.
>
> Select the desired task.
>
> Press `Enter` to start the task.
>
> This was [found on PyCharm's website](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/running-tasks-of-manage-py-utility.html).

Comment: Please help me finding out, if I can run these tasks in the Django (or Python) Console (PyCharm Menu: Tools -> Run Django Console...)